# How to extract a text from an environment variable?

Tags: grep, freebsd

I have a "my-variable-here" environment variable.

e.g.

```
my-variable-here=/var/log/test
```

I want to get the text between the equal sign and the 2nd slash. So in my example above, I want to get the text "/var".

how do I do it?

thanks very much

Comment: Do you parse a shell script and want to parse the environment variable or do you use it (e.g. `echo $my_variable_here | grep ...`)?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a variable that has the value `/var/log/test` or that you have a file containing the text that when executed would set that variable? i.e. are you asking us to help you parse the text `my-variable-here=/var/log/test` or the text `/var/log/test` as would be produced if you did `echo "$my-variable-here"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to use "cut" and slash as a delimiter

```
export my_variable_here=/var/log/test
part2=`echo $my_variable_here | cut -f2 -d"/"`
result="/$part2"
echo $result
```